# How do I call elements like in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i get elements like in jquery? Im looking for the javascript code.

For example:
$(#id)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `document.getElementById('id');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Might as well put that as an answer

Comment: You might want to have a look at the jQuery tutorials: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Comment: Could explain a bit more what you are trying to do? Are you looking for a way to select elements with CSS selectors, without jQuery?

Comment: Don't be afraid to look at the jQuery source code as well. I assume you are new to JS, so you might not understand most of it. But you can still learn quite a bit.\

Comment: the jQuery source can be investigated by simply downloading the not minimized version. Simply have a look into the logic of the selector stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure javascript answer is:

```
document.getElementById('id');
```

Comment: I'd like to add that this works when you  have the ID. If you intend to use some other selector, look at [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Comment: @xbonez yeah, I probably should have linked that, thanks! +1